# Should a web service log exceptions caused by invalid inputs as an error?

Tags: web-services, logging

We have a policy where I work that all web services must log exceptions at the service boundary. If an exception occurs due to invalid inputs, should this be logged as an error?

I think that any time a service can't complete what it was asked to do, that is by default an error, no matter what the reason is. Others think that I should be considering the bigger picture of the system as a whole, and log those exceptions as warnings, because the consumer of the service could handle the exception and correct the inputs. Isn't the fact that the inputs might be corrected in a subsequent request irrelevant to whether or not an error has occurred?

Comment: You're asking for opinions. That's not what this site is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weather error is due to invalid inputs from client or some issue/bug on service side, 
web-service should have error codes for all types of error that can occur.

Now for definite use cases, when you know that client has definitely passed incorrect parameters, you should just return error code to client. You do not need to log this because you don't want to clog your logs as several clients might be calling your service in incorrect ways.

However **if some error occurs which is outside your defined error codes, you should log it as error.**

Comment: We have defined codes for these known input errors and they are returned to the client. My problem is with logging as warnings instead of errors. To me, a warning would only be appropriate for a condition that does not prevent the service operation from completing successfully. Others are concerned that I will be polluting the logs and "real" errors will be missed. I will suggest that we don't log these known input errors, or direct them a separate log.

Comment: Normally I would not log climatic issues, as they are hard to detect ;p